# Probabilities of events

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be events of probabilities $P(A) = p$ and $P(B) = q$ respectively.

(a) What are the largest and smallest possible values that $P(A \cap B)$ could take if $p$ and $q$ are known.

My understanding:
$A$ and $B$ are events in $\Omega$.
1. $A$ and $B$ can be events that are mutually exclusive, in which case $P(A\cap B)=0$.
2. Another possibility is that the two events intersect in $\Omega$. Now this intersection can take certain forms.
a. It could be that $P(A)=P(B)$ i.e. $p=q$, and essentially they are the same event. So $P(A \cap B)$ is either $p$ or $q$ as they are the same.
b. It could be the conventional form of intersection (I don't know how to express this in terms of $p$ and $q$).
3. Finally it could be that $P(A)\subseteq P(B)$ in which case the probability of $p\subset q$ or $P(B)\subseteq P(A)$ i.e. $q\subset p$.

From the above, I can conclude that the smallest value will be $P(A\cap B)=0$ and the largest value $P(A\cap B)=p$ or $q$ (since they are the same, due to $2a$).

Solution based on @lulu's comment

$P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B) = P(A \cup B) \leq1$
$P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B) \leq1$
$P(A)+P(B)\leq1+P(A\cap B)$
Here we can have two possibilities $P(A\cap B) = 0$ (min, mutually exclusive) or $P(A\cap B)\leq1$ (max)
So the smallest value is $0$ and the largest is $1$

b. Express the correlation coefficient $\rho$ of the indicator random variables .

$$\chi_A(\omega) = \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{$:\omega \in A$ }  \\
  0 & \text{: otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

$$and$$

$$\chi_B(\omega) = \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{$:\omega \in B$ }  \\
  0 & \text{: otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

in terms of $P(A),P(B),$ and $P(A\cap B)$

Comment: If $P(A)+P(B)>1$ then it is impossible that $P(A\cap B)=0$.

Comment: If $A \subset B$, then $P(A) = p \leq q = P(B)$.

Comment: @lulu I see. For that, do I need to express two different possibilities? 1 that assumes $P(A)+P(B) \leq 1$ and another for $P(A)+P(B)>1$, as you don't know which you will have?

Comment: Well, you can combine them.  Hint:  Start with $1≥P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.  Your answer will have a minimum or a maximum in it.

Comment: @lulu I attempted your hint, could you please tell me if I succeeded?

Comment: Well...I'd write:  $1≥p+q-P(A\cap B)\implies P(A\cap B)≥ p+q-1\implies P(A\cap B)≥ \max (0,p+q-1)$.

Comment: To be complete, I'd say that $\min (p,q)≥ P(A\cap B)≥ \max (0,p+q-1)$ and note that both bounds are sharp (that is, there are examples where one or the other of the equalities holds).

Comment: @lulu: The usual term is that the bounds are tight.

Comment: @celtschk  I knew that "sharp" felt wrong but my brain refused to supply an alternative.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for the help. However, I am still confused about your notation of $min(p,q)$ and $max(0,p+q-1)$. I don't understand why the min value $0$ is included in the $max$ interval. And I don't understand why $q$ and $p$ are included in the $min$ interval. Perhaps its the notation, but from my understanding and also the answer below, the $min$ is 0, and $max$ is p,q, or 1.

Comment: If $x≥a$ AND $x≥b$ we can summarize that as $x≥\max (a,b)$.  Here you have $P(A\cap B)≥0$ AND $P(A\cap B)≥ p+q-1$ so...

Comment: Similarly, on the other side, we note that $a≥x$ AND $b≥x$ is the same as $\min (a,b)≥x$ and it's clear that $p≥P(A\cap B)$ AND $q≥P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Note:  I think the posted solution from @Arby is somewhere between misleading and flatly wrong.  It is useless to point out that $P(A\cap B)$ lies between $0$ and $1$, that is true for any probability.  Much better bounds are possible when $p,q$ are known.

Comment: @lulu I now understand, thank you. The question contains another part which I have just added. I am very confused about it and don't know how to even start. Would you mind explaining or a certain hint please?

Comment: I'd just use the [straight formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient).  Let$X$ be the indicator for $A$ and $Y$ the indicator for $B$.  Then $\mu_X=p,\mu_Y=q$ and so on.  Key remark is $E[XY]=P(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an upper bound:  Clearly we have $$p≥P(A\cap B)\quad \& \quad q≥P(A\cap B)$$ which together imply that $$\min (p,q)≥P(A\cap B)$$

Note:  this bound can't be improved in general (consider the case where $A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$).

For a lower bound:  of course $P(A\cap B)≥0$.  We also have $$1≥P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)\implies P(A\cap B)≥p+q-1$$

Thus:  $$P(A\cap B)≥ \max (0,p+q-1)$$

Note:  this can't, in general, be improved upon.  We remark that $p≥p+q-1$ and $q≥p+q-1$ so if $p+q-1≥0$ we can construct mutually exclusive events $A',B',C$ with $P(C)=p+q-1$, $P(A')=p-(p+q-1)=1-q$, and $P(B')=q-(p+q-1)=1-p$ and define $A=A'\cup C$ and $B=B'\cup C$.